# wired connection slower than wireless connection

Tags: router

i have a TL-WR641G/642G 108M Wireless LAN Router. im currently putting my wireless settings to 108 mbps(danamic). i live with my roommate who is using a laptop,while im using desktop(cable connected to router). i just wanted to know why and how am i the one cabled but slower than my roommate,as in browsing,games etc. everytime hes surfing(which is a lot)i even had to wait half a minute to open google.

my speed on desktop(cable) only slows down when he is on. but when he not on its just like usual,fast. but when hes on,its like he got my(cable) speed,but im the one getting slower. he is using a macbook.not sure the specification. my desktop is kinda old, xp service pack 3 '02 vers. pentium D 3.40Ghz 1 GB RAM Geforce 7300 GT. seriously im not sure what a malware is. but does spec has to do with internet speed? machine is fine. i could turn on itunes,World of Warcraft,firefox,msn all everything on at the same time no problems. im really sorry,its just i didnt had this problem with my old roommate.thx

Comment: I'm not familiar with that router but I was wondering if there is any existing QoS settings that would favor your roommate.  If so, you can remove the QoS setting, or add your own in an attempt to balance the bandwidth utilization.

Comment: im not quite sure.. How do I know if i have it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be related to your roommate's internet activities.

you may seek an arrangement involving '[Traffic Shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping)' to share the internet connection in a fair and acceptable manner.

This can be achieved with software on the client computers (e.g. [Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html) in your case, i don't know of any equivalent for Mac OS X) or with a router that supports bandwidth shaping via the firmware (e.g. any router that supports DD-WRT or Tomato).

Comment: sorry took me some time,,
well to be honest,im not sure what his activities are. so do u think Traffic Shaping will help?as in like 50-50 fair? but is there a way to sumhow slow his connection down a lil bit? cuz i mean im the one paying fully,50-50 still doesnt do much fair dont u think?

Comment: @arman - yes, you can equally divide the bandwidth between clients (or any percentage that suits you since you're the one paying the bill :). get a cheap WRT54G router and then install 3rd party firmware like DD-WRT or Tomato.

Comment: oh that clears things up. thank you so much :D

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explain a little more as there is not really enough information for an informative answer.

However -

How was your speed when you were on Wireless?
 - If it is as fast, there may be a problem.

How was his speed when he is on wired?
 - Again, if it is the same, there may be a probem.

What is the specifiction of his laptop?

What is the specification of your desktop?

Is your machine clean, or does it have any malware?

Without more information, I would go with - It could just be that your machine is slower than his